# Variable expansion in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable-substitution

I tried the following commands

```
variable='one|name'
echo $variable
```

The output is

```
one|name
```

whereas `echo one|name` gives an error `No command 'name' found`. This is reasonable because bash treats `|` as a pipe and tries to execute command `name` with `one` as input.

But why does `echo $variable` print `one|name`? After Parameter and Variable expansion, shouldn't it be equivalent to `echo one|name`?

**Version:**

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: How would you like it if it were `variable='foo|rm -rf /'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it shouldn't, because of the way `bash` [operate the command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation).

When you type `echo one|name`, `bash` parse the command, treats `|` as a pipe token, so `|` perform pipeline.

When you type `echo $variable`, because token parsing occur before variable expansion, `bash` parsing the command into two parts, `echo` and `$variable`. After that, it performs variable expansion, expand `$variable` to `one|name`. In this case, `one|name` is a string, `|` is a part of string and can not be treated as a pipe token (of course, [the token recognition phrase](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) was done). The only thing it can be special if `IFS` variable contains `|`, `bash` will use `|` as delimiter to perform field spliting:

```
$ variable='one|name'
$ IFS='|'
$ echo $variable
one name
```

Comment: Wow! didn't consider the parsing part.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because of the way `Bash` expands the variable.

Instead of expanding the variable to `one|name` it expands the variable to `"one|name"`. So here as the value is enclosed within quotes they are treated as string instead of a command.

Below is the `strace` output of the command which shows how the command gets expanded.

```
$ variable='one|name'
$ strace echo $variable 
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "one|name"], [/* 33 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9cc7000
```

Comment: Does this happen for all variable expansions?

Comment: No, it's not the way `bash` expands variables. It's the way `bash` parsing the command.

Comment: But the `strace` command is interesting. Didn't know it before.

Comment: yes this is the way variables gets expanded in `bash`. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html  give you details on how shell expansion happens.

Answer (score -2):

The quotes are part of the string you created.

If you did

```
variable=one|name
echo $variable
```

the result would be as expected. But you are only able to do this in a script (thanks for the helpful comment).

Comment: `variable=one|name` itself would give an error

Comment: True, you have to put it in a script, I adjust the answer. Thank you!